# Why is type-graphql not able to infer a string type that is from a property of a class?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I have a type/class `Foo` that have a property `bar` of type `string`.

```
class Foo {
    bar: string
}
```

If I use an `Arg` (from `type-graphql`) without passing explicitly the type and pass the argument type to `string`. Everything works, e.g.

```
doSomething(
  @Arg('bar') bar: string,
){
  // whatever
}
```

But if I pass the type of the `bar` property of `Foo` (which is string), it doesn't work, e.g.

```
doSomething(
  @Arg('bar') bar: Foo['bar'], // this property type is string
){
  // whatever
}
```

By "is doesn't work" I mean, it gives me the unable to infer error

> Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. You need to provide explicit type for argument named 'bar' of 'doSomething' of 'FooResolver' class

Why it cannot infer the type? Shouldn't it be able to infer the type?

Answer (score 2):

> Why it cannot infer the type? Shouldn't it be able to infer the type?

That's TypeScript compiler limitation - emitted reflect metadata is restricted only to simple and explicit cases, like `: string` is reflected to runtime `String`.

For generics and lookups, how would to transform type value to runtime value?